# If the above function is f(x) then f'(x) vanishes at?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$1+x+\int_1^x\left(\text{ln}^2\left(t\right)+2\text{ln}\left(t\right)\right)dt$$

If the above function is f(x) then f'(x) vanishes at which value of x? I am trying this question by taking the integrating part as z and then I am rewriting f(x) =1+x+z. After this I am thinking for applying Newton Leibnitz rule. But the fact is that I am unable to solve any more. Kindly help me out

Comment: If you apply the Fondamental theorem of calculus there is no integration to do. Then, you may solve the polynomial you obtain by doing $\ln(x) = X$. Also, please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics on this site instead of images.

Comment: Kindly show it to me by doing. I am not able to understand how to solve

Comment: This is just a comment, hence not an answer. :)

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $f'(x)=1+(\ln x )^{2}+2\ln x$. Hence, $f'(x)=[1+\ln x]^{2}=0$  if and only if $\ln x =-1$ or $x=\frac 1 e$.

Comment: I also found the answer to be 1/e but in the book the answer given is 1+(2/e)

Comment: The book is wrong. @DEEPANWITAROY

Comment: Ok. Might be the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, you derive the function. Then you get:
$$1+(\int_1^x(\ln^2(t)+2ln(t))dt)'=1+\ln^2(x)+2ln(x)$$
This happen thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus. Then, this is a binomial form. So you can simplify to $(1+\ln(x))^2$. Then... ¿For what value you can get to be equal 0? The answer is $x=\frac{1}{e}$.